# Trying to use percentages for Responsive CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design

I whipped up this site at http://www.flywavez.com/ and have it mostly situated (I have to even up a few margins a pixel here, a pixel there), but I went to check it on the iPhone, Android (galaxy s3 running 4.3, Chrome and the android browser), iPad, and Kindle and I don't think my CSS margins are being interpreted how they are in the screen browsers (i.e. - desktops and laptops).

I used percentages on my margins, and even tried padding, but I can't find that balance where the elements display relatively uniform. Should I specify a separate style sheet just for mobile with the different margins? For the phones, it seems like .socials ( a sprite, btw) would have a margin-left of 0, with a few on top to kick it down some.

The same for #quick-mid-text, on a seperate phone browser, the margin would be left 0.

However I want to keep it as much in one style sheet as possible. What should I use as margins or element arrangement to render the social media icons to be centered under the player, and for the paragraph in #quick-mid-text to be flush with the left edge of the player?

Here's my CSS:

```
.socials {
float: right;
padding-top: 13px;
margin-right: 40%;
width:275px;
}

.socials a {
display: block;
width: 58px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background: url(../images/socials2.png) 0 0 no-repeat; 
}

.socials a:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
}

.socials a+a {
margin-left: 12px;
background-position: -62px 0;
width: 56px;
}

.socials a+a+a {
margin-left: 4px;
background-position: -120px;
width: 32px;
}

.socials a+a+a+a {
margin-left: 4px;
background-position: -156px; 
width: 93px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use media queries to change styles based on screen width. You can do base styles and then override them etc in your media query.

Eg:

```
.socials {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 13px;
  margin-right: 40%;
  width:275px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) {
    .socials {
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be working, but I have to change it to margin-right, and probably add a few more, at different res's and such. I kind of learned something with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This css...

```
#quick-mid-text {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 13px;
    width: 42%;
}
.socials {    /* style.css -line no.756*/
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding-top: 0;
    width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: so if I'm understanding correctly, all I really have to do is detect what resolution, device, or browser is displaying undesirably - and then write a media query with it's specs and style accordingly?

Comment: ya i am using media query but mostly use full % in width,height.